# Library for playing Audio files in Linux C

Tags: c, linux, audio

I want to play audio files using my C programs in Linux. Can any one suggest me good development libraries for playing audio files in Linux?

Answer (score 3):

GStreamer. [gstreamer.net](http://gstreamer.net)

Answer (score 1):

[FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

```
 FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert
 and stream audio and video. It includes libavcodec - the leading audio/video
 codec library.
```